# Why Would WIFEXITED Return True on Running Process?

Tags: c, system-calls

When I wait on a specific running process group that is a child process, WIFEXITED returns true saying the process exited?  Is this the way it works? Seems there is something I am not understanding....

```
if ( waitpid(-pgid, &pstatus, WUNTRACED|WNOHANG ) == -1)
    perror("Wait error");

if ( WIFEXITED(pstatus) ) {
    strncpy(buf,  "Exited", buf_size);
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you specified `WNOHANG` I think `waitpid` is returning `0` and `pstatus` has the value it had before so `WIFEXITED` is not working with updated data.

> if `WNOHANG` was specified and one or more child(ren) 
>   specified by `pid` exist, but have not yet changed state, 
>   then `0` is returned.

Comment: Ah, I did reinitialize to 0, but now I sort of understand.  but I don't quite understand how to tell if something is still running or if it exited (without blocking).

Comment: If any of your children changed status(died) waitpid will return a positive number.

Comment: Oh I understand now... I Need to take both the return value and the status value to get the status of the process. (Return value is not just for error or not). Thank you!

Comment: The WIFE has left and the children died from the shock.

Comment: @James Morris: I thought the WIFE was EXCITED that the children were still alive...

Comment: doc is not clear here - it should state that status is written under some conditions only. Worse WIFEXITED(0) == true, it just indicates there was no signal

Answer (score 1):

`waitpid` returns the reaped child pid if it successfully reaps a child. When used with `WNOHANG`, it immediately returns 0 if no children have exited. Thus, you need to check whether the return value is 0 or a pid before you inspect `status`. See here for details:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html